# Unexpected $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess events broadcasted in ionic unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, ionic-framework, jasmine

I'm implementing unit tests for ionic application and need to check that no events have been broadcasted on $rootScope

```
expect($rootScope.$broadcast).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The problem is sometimes there are $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess events broadcasted which makes my tests fail. It seems that ionic v1.3.0 triggers those in the below code

```
// update browser
$rootScope.$watch(function $locationWatch() {
  var oldUrl = trimEmptyHash($browser.url());
  var newUrl = trimEmptyHash($location.absUrl());
  var oldState = $browser.state();
  var currentReplace = $location.$$replace;
  var urlOrStateChanged = oldUrl !== newUrl ||
    ($location.$$html5 && $sniffer.history && oldState !== $location.$$state);

  if (initializing || urlOrStateChanged) {
    initializing = false;

    $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
      var newUrl = $location.absUrl();
      var defaultPrevented = $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', newUrl, oldUrl,
          $location.$$state, oldState).defaultPrevented;
```

The "initializing" flag is true in the above code and this triggers $rootScope.$broadcast.
Question - why is it happening? And what is the best way to handle this situation?
Right now I added $rootScope.$digest(); before acting in my tests which seemed to fix the problem however I'm not sure if this is valid solution

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might be more of a comment than an answer, but I do not have enough reputation to write a comment.

Isn't $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess fired before everything else? Even before $rootScope? As I understand $locationChangeStart has higher priority level then $rootScope.

Do you have anything within app.on(function () {}); ?